# PHP update syntax error for SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax, sql-update

Below is my code I have check many times to ensure that is no error but the chrome keep give me an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com, Account_Title=Mr, Account_Dob=2018-08-09, Account_Phone1=123, Accoun' at line 1' in C:\wamp64\www\TAO\UserProfileupdate.php on line 15

May I know what is this mean by ?

```
$sql = "UPDATE account_info 
  SET Account_Email=$email, Account_Title=$title, Account_Dob=$dob,
      Account_Phone1=$phoneno, Account_Phone2=$sphoneno,
      Account_Home_No=$homeno, Account_Office_No=$officeno";
```

Comment: Learn to use parameters rather than munging query strings with constant values.

Comment: Use prepared statements. The issues will be solved. Strings in SQL need to be quoted is the short answer.

Comment: Those are strings, not integers and they require to be quoted.

Comment: You also probably want a `WHERE` clause or all your records will be updated.

Comment: omg.....I look at this query for an hour now only I know that this small mistake I make......

Comment: thanks so much....!!!